# Free software for connecting to a Nokia phone to transfer music

Tags: bluetooth, music, nokia-pc-suite

What free software is there for connecting to a Nokia phone?  Nokia recently "upgraded" their PC Suite with a music manager that isn't compatible with my phone, and frankly, PC Suite sucks so much that I'd be happy not to use it.

Is there any other free software for connecting a PC to a Nokia phone?  Specifically, I'm looking for something that I can use to transfer music.

Comment: Are you using bluetooth to do that? If so my answer is not valid. I can see the bluetooth tag but I can't see any description. I assumed you have the cable :(

Answer (score 3):

Most Nokia phones these days have USB connectivity. You could always just plug it in as a 'Mass Storage Device" and load songs on it that way. eHow has a guide to [How to Sync Music to an MP3 Player Using Windows Media Player](http://www.ehow.com/how_4530644_sync-music-mp3-player-using.html) which should be able to be used with your phone.

On my Mac I use bluetooth to transfer the odd song here-and-there (but it is just too slow for transferring whole collections)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [vDisk](http://vampent.com/vdisk.htm)?

```
What is vDisk?

    vDisk is a remote file manager that help you manage mobile from PC.
It can transfer very large files directly to mobile via bluetooth,GPRS,
infrared and usb. It is also an effective tool to install roms for vNes,
vBoy,vSun.
```

It's a free trial, less than $10 to buy.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you access the phone using USB mode. When you use the USB mode the computer treats the memory as a removable memory (Like a flash drive). You can simply copy the music files and play with the player after disconnecting the USB connection. Personally I like this method to avoid the unnecessary problems with that nokia pc suite. The latest version's music manager sucks.. :(

Comment: The latest version's music manager simply doesn't work with my phone.  I'm using an old version, and installation is getting stuck

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like their software. (I am sorry if you agree with me). All of the Nokia on Windows (PC Suite, Music Manager, Ovi Suite and Ovi Suite 2) are failed to manage music very well with my player.

If you never put your music in phone's memory but on a MicroSD card, and if you like Foobar2000. You can do what I do.
(You can use connect your phone in "Mass storage mode" but it is a quite slower in my exp.)

- Use a card reader to synchronize your music; which is usually much more faster and more stable.
- Create a new playlist in Foobar2000, which will be the music list to be synchronized to your phone.
- Remove your card from device, and plug it into your PC. Open your foobar2000 and use the copy feature under "File operation". Copy all of them on your list; exists files will be skipped.
- Once a while, delete the music from card manually (which I do once a quarter)

The major problem(I think) of Nokia's tools are: "They will always try to scan your folders when it is running." It is a problem if you have a lots of files.

PROS:

- You have a master list of music in your PC.
- You can add items when your device is not connected.
- It is the fastest if you have a lot's of files to be copied.

CONS:

- You will have to convert it to device playable format before you add it to your list.
  (It is funny that the few AAC are not playable even if it was converted by Nokia's tool.)
- Not everyone likes foobar2000
- Not compatible to DRM (?)
- It is not anyway to synchronize files back to PC.

Answer (score 0):

I use PC Suite / USB-mode / Bluetooth to transfer music to my Nokia E66. Really does depend if I'm on a PC with PC-suite on it or not.

I haven't really had any problems transferring music with PC-suite, but i do prefer the file-manageability of using windows explorer directly

Comment: But how do you access playlists without using PC-suite?  I can never find them